# c++ How to call child method in abstract parent class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract

I have a problem with my code.

```
class A{
    virtual foo()=0;
}

class B: public A {
    foo();
    foo2();
    operator X(A * a) {a->foo2()}   //doesn't work
}

class C: public A {
    foo();
    foo2();
    operator X(A * a) {a->foo2()} //doesn't work.
}
```

So I have a virtual class, and 2 classes that inherit from it. And I have to define an operator X that acts on an A object, no matter if it is B or C (since it can't be A because A is abstract). The problem is that the operator calls foo2(), which I'm not allowed to write in class A. What should I do?

Thanks a lot for helping me. This is my first post.

Comment: Change the operator signature to `X(B * a)`.

Comment: It is because `foo2()` is not the part of class A.

Comment: I can't change the operator signature. I am supposed to have my operator X work, no matter if it is a B or a C. I only see it as an A...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *right* answer is to declare `foo2` pure virtual in A.  However you have been told you are not allowed to do this.  Boo :-(

Your only remaining option is to use `dynamic_cast`.

```
void do_foo2(A* a)
{
    if (B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(b))
        return b->foo2();
    C& c = dynamic_cast<C&>(*a);  // Will throw if a is not B or C.
    return c.foo2();
}
```

Then

```
void B::operator X(A* a)
{
    do_foo2(a);
}
```

Note:  This all assumes you are supposed to make `B::operator X` work with both B and C.

Comment: Yes, this makes so much sense! Thank you, I've just spent a whole day on this :-)